# SAP Hybris: How to load app context in custom error page controller?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm using SAP Hybris 1811 on my local machine. I've got custom error page handler in `web.xml`

```
<error-page>
        <exception-type>java.lang.NullPointerException</exception-type>
        <location>/errors</location>
</error-page>
```

And a controller for handling this error (note it's not extending `AbstractPageController`, for reason read further)

```
@Controller
public class ErrorController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/errors", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView handleErrors(Model model, HttpServletRequest httpRequest) {
        httpRequest.getLocale();
        .... some code here
    }
}
```

I need to get correct current `locale` of the app for displaying correct language in error page, but it's still getting only English, although it should be other language.

I tried to load `i18nService` and it's locale for example like this, but it's still "en":

```
SpringHelper.getSpringBean(httpRequest, "i18nService", DefaultI18NService.class, true).getCurrentLocale()
```

I thought the problem was because of the `ErrorController` doesn't extend `AbstractPageController`, but when I tried that, none of the error methods could be reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I was able to get the correct locale like this:

```
Locale loc = ((Locale)((CommerceJaloSession)this.pageContext.getSession().getAttribute("jalosession")).getAttribute("locale"));
```

Answer (score 0):

We have used controller advice concept of Spring MVC where you should be able to receive all the information. Also this way, the error would be caught in the storefront itself and you will have good control there.

```
@ControllerAdvice(basePackages =
{ "com.custom", "de.hybris.platform", "org.springframework" })
public class GlobalControllerExceptionHandler
{
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(GlobalControllerExceptionHandler.class);

    private static final String FORWARD_TO_ERROR_PAGE = ControllerConstants.FORWARD_STMT
            + ControllerConstants.ControllerMappings.Error.ErrorController;

    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public String handleException(final Exception exception, final HttpServletRequest request)
    {
        LOG.error("Exception caught :: " + exception.getMessage(), exception);
        request.setAttribute(ControllerConstants.ControllerMappings.Error.ExceptionAttributeName, exception);
        return FORWARD_TO_ERROR_PAGE;

    }
}
```